# Linked Lists Help C++

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list

I am having trouble in C++ putting and displaying array into a linked list. I'm having lots of trouble with linked lists in general

Here is my code. It only displays the first number. (It should display 19 21 17 22 33)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node {
    int age;
    node *next;
};

void display(node *t)
{
    node *temp = t;
    cout << temp->age << " ";
}

int main()
{
    int Age[5] = { 19, 21, 17, 22, 33 };

    node* List = new node;
    List = NULL;
    node* temp2 = List;

    while (temp2 != NULL)
    {
        temp2 = temp2->next;
        node* List = new node;
        List = NULL;
        node* temp2 = List;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        temp2 = new node;
        temp2 -> age = Age[i];
        temp2 -> next = NULL;

        if (List == NULL) 
            List = temp2;
    }

    display(List);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `List = NULL;` followed by `node* temp2 = List;`. Now you have 2 pointers pointing to `NULL` and your node that was allocated via `node* List = new node;` leaked. Fix that first

Comment: I highly recommend searching the internet for "C++ linked list example".  Probably a lot faster than debugger through StackOverflow.

Comment: Visualization really helps with linked lists. Draw the list on a piece of paper. Draw in the links. Step by step modify the list as you insert, remove, or otherwise modify the list. Keep good notes of the steps you took and use the notes as the basis for your code. Afterward follow the the instructions you coded and draw the same list. If you can't, you have a bug and probably a really good idea where you went wrong.

Comment: A really helpful trick is to add a constructor to the node that sets `next` to `NULL` if you don't provide a different link. That way you can't forget to set `next`.

Comment: You are not using `next` correctly in several places. You change the head pointer when you should have changed the `next`  pointer to the last node in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the following code as an example. Note that you have to delete all created nodes at the end of program to avoid memory leaks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

using namespace std;

struct node {
    int age;
    node* next;
};

void display(node* list) {
    while (list != NULL) {
        cout << list->age << ' ';
        list = list->next;
    }
}

node* create(int age) {
    node* t = new node;
    t->age = age;
    t->next = NULL;
    return t;
}

void add(node* list, node* t) {
    while (list->next != NULL) {
        list = list->next;
    }
    list->next = t;
}

void release(node* list) {
    while (list != NULL) {
        node* t = list;
        list = list->next;
        delete t;
    }
}

int main() {
    int arr[5] = { 19, 21, 17, 22, 33 };

    node* list = create(arr[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        node* t = create(arr[i]);
        add(list, t);
    }

    display(list);

    release(list);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot going on here.  I'd recommend you look through some tutorials to help solidify your understanding of pointers and linked lists.

To answer your question, let's step through what's happening:

In your `main` function, you dynamically allocate a `node` object and have `List` point to this object.  Then, you set `List` to `NULL`.  When you initialize the `node` pointer `temp2` to `List`, `temp2` also points to `NULL`.

Because `temp2 = NULL`, you skip over the following `while` loop.

In the first iteration of your `for` loop, you re-assign `temp2` to a newly created object, then set the `age` for that `node` to the `Age[0]`.  When we get to your `if` statement, `List = NULL` so we enter the conditional statement and set `List` to `temp2` where `temp2->age = Age[0]`.

For each additional iteration of your `for` loop, `List` no longer is equal to `NULL` so you never enter your `if` statement again.  `List` still points to the `node` where `age = Age[0]`.

When you get to your display function, assuming it was written to loop through a linked list, your `List` pointer is a list with one node where `age = 19`.  Assuming your had a linked list with multiple valid nodes, your `display()` function doesn't iterate over them.